# Oracle - update timestamp to GMT before inserting into the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to implement the audit mechanism for our application so that all messages, errors, request/response etc. will be logged centrally in one table 'PROJECT_AUDIT'.
Below stored proc will be used to insert the data into 'PROJECT_AUDIT' table.
Here, I want to convert 'p_timestamp' value received as input to this stored proc into GMT time zone.

Can you please help.
Stored Procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROJECT_AUDIT_INSERT_RECORD(
       p_message_Type IN PROJECT_AUDIT.message_type%TYPE,
       p_component_Name IN PROJECT_AUDIT.component_name%TYPE,
       p_username IN PROJECT_AUDIT.USERNAME%TYPE,
       p_timestamp IN PROJECT_AUDIT.timestamp%TYPE,
       p_request_Number IN PROJECT_AUDIT.request_number%TYPE,
       p_module_Name IN PROJECT_AUDIT.module_name%TYPE,
       p_process_name IN PROJECT_AUDIT.process_name%TYPE,
       p_version IN PROJECT_AUDIT.version%TYPE,
       p_task IN PROJECT_AUDIT.task%TYPE,
       p_error_Code PROJECT_AUDIT.error_code%TYPE,
       p_error_Message PROJECT_AUDIT.error_message%TYPE,
       p_message PROJECT_AUDIT.message%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO PROJECT_AUDIT ("MESSAGE_TYPE", "COMPONENT_NAME", "USERNAME", "TIMESTAMP", "REQUEST_NUMBER", "MODULE_NAME", "PROCESS_NAME", "VERSION", "TASK", "ERROR_CODE", "ERROR_MESSAGE", "MESSAGE") 
  VALUES (p_message_Type, p_component_Name, p_username, p_timestamp, p_request_Number, p_module_Name, p_process_name, p_version, p_task, p_error_Code, p_error_Message, p_message);

  COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_AUDIT (
ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
MESSAGE_TYPE VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
COMPONENT_NAME VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
USERNAME VARCHAR2(32 CHAR),
TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
REQUEST_NUMBER VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
MODULE_NAME VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
PROCESS_NAME VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
VERSION VARCHAR2(64 CHAR),
TASK VARCHAR2(128 CHAR),
ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2(256 CHAR),
ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
);
```

Comment: What is the data type of `p_timestamp`?  Is it `timestamp`?  `timestamp with time zone`?  Something else?  If `p_timestamp` does not include a time zone, the caller would need to tell you what time zone it is in or you would have to know what time zone it is in before you could convert it to a different time zone

Comment: @JustinCave, Sorry, I missed it while posting the question. Data type of timestamp is 'TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL'. I have updated the question as well. Also, caller will send me the timezone value. I want to convert it into GMT before inserting into the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `at time zone` to convert it.

```
p_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
```

will return a new `timestamp with time zone` which has been converted to UTC (aka GMT).  See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=989b224d8304b2d662ce647c0d2ef320) for an example.